# Missing JavaHL Library

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, javahl

I am running Eclipse on OS X (10.6.8) and primarily work with SVN 1.6.  I have subclipse installed as well.

In eclipse I get the following error when I save files:

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
```

So I did some research and found that it was because I needed to install the JavaHL Library, which I attempted to do based on information on this page: http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

The approach I following based on the information at the previous link was to install MacPorts (which was successsful) and run the following command to install the JavaHL Library:

```
sudo port install subversion-javahlbindings +no_bdb +universal
```

However, what I didn't know was that this command installed the JavaHL Library with a version number of 1.7.7_0 which doesn't work since I need version 1.6.x so I uninstalled this version of the JavaHL Library.  I can't seem to find how I can get version 1.6 of JavaHL installed on my computer using macports.  I visited the MacPorts website, but they do not presently have a port for version 1.6.

Any help on this problem is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you can get 1.7 from http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#osx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use Subclipse 1.8.x which requires SVN 1.7?  The version of SVN on your server does not matter.  You should just use SVN 1.7 on the client as it is faster and more reliable.  Now that you have MacPorts installed, you have a SVN 1.7.7 command line client to use as well.  The only area where the client version matters is when you try to use more than one client on the same working copy.  In that scenario, the major.minor version of the clients should match.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I don't know why I hadn't noticed that during the installation of JavaHL via MacPorts that my SVN client was updated to 1.7.  DOH!   Anyway, I performed an `svn upgrade` on my working copy, updated my subclipse plugin to 1.8 and voila, no more error.  Haven't yet committed any files so hopefully that works without issue.  Thanks again!